# How to use value of variable (holding integer value) from JDBC request in while loop?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JDBC request to fetch row count -  'rownum' of a table. Now I need to do some additional SQL operations in separate JDBC request in which I need to extract data of only 2 rows at a time which I am able to handle using counter. Now I need to decrease the rownum by 2 as I have already used two rows of the table. So I am trying to use while loop in which I would have while rownum>0. But I . have no idea how to use the output variable of first JDBC request which will hold the integer value in while loop. I also need to subtract 2 from this in every iteration.

The output variable name of first JDBC request is "count_num"

Then I used beanshell to parse this as integer using following code:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("{count_num}").trim());
```

This beanshell sampler is also failing. I even tried using vars.get("count_num"), but that also failed stating ::

> Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int i = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("count_dcn").trim());'' : Typed variable declaration

Now in my while loop, I want to use this value of I (no idea how to do it, should I be using ${i}).

[image: while loop]

I also need to subtract 2 from the value of I probably at the end of while loop (after second forEach controller maybe), again not sure how to do it.

Structure of Test Plan:
[image: Test Plan]

Comment: I tried using count_num_1 in beanshell processor and it passed. Seems like "i" will have the count_num value stored in that case. But still the challenge is how to use value of "i" in while loop or other samplers/controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${__javaScript(parseInt(${count_dcn_1})>0)}
```

this code worked